# How to exit the previously opened function created from socketio.start_background_task() when new connection is being made

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

Every time when I refresh the page from client side a new connection is made with the flask server and it runs the function 'backgroundFunction()' without exiting the recent opened function and the number increases as I refresh the page again and again.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit
import socket
from time import sleep
import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

socketio = SocketIO(app , cors_allowed_origins="*" , async_mode = None , logger = False , engineio_logger = False)


def backgroundFunction():

    while True:
        data = "I am Data"
        socketio.emit('data', data, broadcast=True)
        socketio.sleep(2)


@socketio.on('connect')
def socketcon():
    print('Client connected')
    socketio.start_background_task(backgroundFunction)


if __name__ == ("__main__"):
    socketio.run(app, port=5009)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the example code in the Flask-SocketIO repository to learn one possible way to implement a background job that starts the first time an event is triggered.

Code is [here](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/blob/master/example/app.py). Here is the relevant excerpt:

```py
thread = None
thread_lock = Lock()

def background_thread():
    """Example of how to send server generated events to clients."""
    count = 0
    while True:
        socketio.sleep(10)
        count += 1
        socketio.emit('my_response',
                      {'data': 'Server generated event', 'count': count})

@socketio.event
def connect():
    global thread
    with thread_lock:
        if thread is None:
            thread = socketio.start_background_task(background_thread)
```